# One (or n) level reverse nesting in SASS

Tags: sass, nested

you surely know reverse nesting in sass. So i got an advanced question for you.

```
.profile{
    .avatar{
        color: blue;  
        .friends &{            
            color: grey;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.friends .profile .avatar {
```

How to get a result like:

```
.profile.friends .avatar {
```

Is there a solution with out changing the structure of the sass.

Comment: Is the lack of a space between `.profile.friends` a typo or the wanted output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you must change the structure of the Sass.  The upcoming `@at-root` feature can partially unwind selectors, but it will not work in this instance.

Comment: Just what I was afraid of.